# Compute distances between all points in array efficiently using Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

I have a list of `N=3` points like this as input:
`points = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4]]`

I wrote this code to compute all possible distances between all elements of my list `points`, as `dist = min(∣x1−x2∣,∣y1−y2∣)`:

```
distances = []
for i in range(N-1):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        dist = min((abs(points[i][0]-points[j][0]), abs(points[i][1]-points[j][1])))
        distances.append(dist)
print(distances)
```

My output will be the array `distances` with all the distances saved in it: `[1, 3, 2]`

It works fine with `N=3`, but I would like to compute it in a more efficiently way and be free to set `N=10^5`.
I am trying to use also `numpy` and `scipy`, but I am having a little trouble with replacing the loops and use the correct method.

Can anybody help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how many distances you will be calculating with a set of `10^5` points? Do you think that's a reasonable thing to try to calculate?

Comment: You can use [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), or you can use simple broadcasting. But as @MarkMeyer says, your data is just too big for pair-wise distance. Basically `5*10^9` pairs, which is about 40GB of memory.

Comment: Hi! I know, it sounds crazy, but in this task (I am just doing some exercises to improve myself) https://csacademy.com/contest/archive/task/strange-distance/statement/ there's written that N could be 10^5. So, I though it was an idea (not necessarily a good one) to aim to it. Obviously, this is not the solution of the task, but just a part of it (the code in this question is not for k-th distance of course)

Comment: Ho can ```cdist``` improve my code? Shall I just substitute ```min((abs(points[i][0]-points[j][0]), abs(points[i][1]-points[j][1])))``` with ```cdist(i, j)``` or do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The *numpythonic* solution

To compute your distances using the full power of *Numpy*, and do it
substantially faster:

1. Convert your *points* to a *Numpy* array:

   ```
    pts = np.array(points)
   ```
2. Then run:

   ```
    dist = np.abs(pts[np.newaxis, :, :] - pts[:, np.newaxis, :]).min(axis=2)
   ```

Here the result is a **square** array.
But if you want to get a **list** of elements above the diagonal,
just like your code generates, you can run:

```
dist2 = dist[np.triu_indices(pts.shape[0], 1)].tolist()
```

I ran this code for the following *9* points:

```
points = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4], [3, 5], [2, 8], [4, 10], [3, 7], [2, 9], [4, 7]]
```

For the above data, the result saved in *dist* (a full array) is:

```
array([[0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2],
       [3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2],
       [3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0]])
```

and the list of elements from upper diagonal part is:

```
[1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
  2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2]
```

## How faster is my code

It turns out that even for such small sample like I used (**9**
points), my code works **2 times faster**. For a sample of 18 points
(not presented here) - **6** times faster.

This difference in speed has been gained even though my function
computes "2 times more than needed" i.e. it generates a **full**
array, whereas the lower diagonal part of the result in a "mirror
view" of the upper diagonal part (what computes your code).

For bigger number of points the difference should be much bigger.
Make your test on a bigger sample of points (say 100 points) and write how
many times faster was my code.

Comment: Your code and your explanation are fantastic!! Thank you very much for your help!!!